# Init system with dependency handling and service file format on *BSD

Tags: init, bsd

I'd like to know whether there are any Systemd equivalents for *BSD distributions, basically something that can handle dependencies between services (service A requires B to be started, so until B is ready don't start A) and has a sane service file format (like a configuration file that tells it what to start and when, instead of an initscript).

After using it on Linux I can't even think of going back to a legacy initscripts-based distribution, and yet I'd like to try a BSD (I need a very minimal system for a router & access point).

Answer (score 1):

FreeBSD's init system has dependency. Please check [man rcorder](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rcorder%288%29&sektion=):

> The rcorder utility is designed to    print out a dependency ordering of a
>        set of interdependent files.  Typically it is used to find an execution
>        sequence for a set of shell scripts in which certain files must be executed before others.

If your service isn't too complicated then its rc-script would simple too. If your service is complicated, the systemd unit file will be complicated too. See the [rc.d scripting documentation](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/rc-scripting/article.html#rcng-daemon):

```
#!/bin/sh

. /etc/rc.subr

name=mumbled
rcvar=mumbled_enable

command="/usr/sbin/${name}"

load_rc_config $name
run_rc_command "$1"
```

I think it's not complicated. More details see the documentations!

Answer (score 1):

FreeBSD gives you a nice simple way to do this in the rc.d scripts.

Look at `man rc`. You'll see how the order is worked out. In essence, you state what service a script provides, and which services it needs to be running first. Here's an example:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# PROVIDE: foo
# REQUIRE: bar_service_required_to_precede_foo
```

The rest should happen automagically.